# What's the longest question you have ever seen here on SO?

Tags: discussion, fun

I just stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071309/not-getting-the-details-from-databasemysql), which has a huge amount of information ([screenshot](http://pieterhordijk.com/alottainfo.png) in case it changes).

Are there any longer questions found on SO? What's the longest question you've encountered?

Comment: Also, the OP would like you to "intimate" him/her if you have any doubts.

Comment: By longest you don't mean thickest, right?

Comment: @Rob: hahaha. Yeah he would like that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's less interesting when you realize there's a maximum post length of 30000 characters. In any case, you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to find out. According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109642/) the longest post is [XSLT Ignores some `<apply-template .. >` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265503/xslt-ignores-some-apply-template-tags), at 39220 characters (I'm not sure how it's so long; possibly the post length checker ignores some data, or the rendered HTML takes up a lot of space)

Comment: spoil it for us ;) Neh thanks for info. The beauty of the question you posted is the fact that stuff apparently got truncated and it continues in the comment :D

Comment: @Michael it's worth noting that's the largest post, not the longest post. The one linked by OP has more lines in it than the one listed there. Conveniently, a lot of the text in the post you linked is wrapped inside code boxes with scroll bars, making it easy to read. I can reach the end of it with 2 page downs on my screen, while the OP's requires 10.

Comment: I wonder if it's because the OP edited almost 19k characters in during an edit.  Do edits not check the max post length?

Comment: @Daniel They do (just tested)

Comment: It's easy to confirm that 39220 is the length of the rendered data (you can download it with the [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/6265503\?body=true) and count its characters at your leasure). The markdown [source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b1e37a01-82a9-4dfd-9e5e-27d3e2d5d908/view-source) is 23773 characters.